# Python - How to get connections OS type?

Tags: python, sockets, operating-system

How can I get the connected users OS type?
because when I use os.name from the OS module it shows my servers OS type not the users

Code:

```
import socket
import threading
from thread import start_new_thread

connect = ""
conport = 8080

def clientThread(conn):
    while True:
        message = conn.recv(512)

        if message.lower().startswith("quit"):
            conn.close()

        if not message:
            break

def startClient():
    host = connect
    port = conport
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(1)
    print("[+] Server Started")
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()

        start_new_thread(clientThread, (conn,))
    sock.close()

client = threading.Thread(target=startClient)
client.start()
```

Comment: Where is `os.name` in your code?

Comment: "because when I use os.name from the OS module it shows my servers OS type not the users", yes, that's how that works. Why do you want to get the user's operating system type? There's a very good chance that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). Socket communication won't automatically tell you this. It doesn't care what the other OS (or programming language) is. Why do you?

Comment: I deleted os.name from the code DYZ cause it don't work

Comment: I care for my own reason chris I just need a way to do it

Comment: @FeitanPortor, if you could provide more context for why we may be able to provide a better answer. "Because I want to" is counterproductive. It _literally doesn't matter_ what the other OS is with socket programming. Your only way will be for the client to send a specific message telling you, which is possible, but awkward and there is probably a better solution to achieve your _actual_ goal. Again, I urge you to read about the XY problem.

Comment: Okay I got curious how to do it because an exploit software that uses sockets does it, it is called eternalblue and it somehow gets the IP's OS name when connected

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is called fingerprinting and you won't get it from a simple system call. Lookup nmap-os-db for an exemple.

Comment: How did EternalBlue.py do it then?

Comment: @FeitanPortor: if you mean [this code](https://github.com/pythonone/MS17-010/tree/master/exploits/eternalblue) - what makes you think that it checks the type of the target OS in the first place?

Comment: It is not that code, the code I refer to is an exploit

Answer (score 0):

I use this algorithm:

```
def get_os():
    import socket

    if 'macbook' in socket.gethostname().lower():
        return 'macos'
    elif 'windows' in socket.gethostname().lower():
        return 'windows'
    else:
        return 'linux(ubuntu)'
print("Currently os:", get_os())
```

I just check, if in `socket.gethostname()` has in platform name.